# Why don't stationary electric charges possess a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism

Why don't stationary electric charges posses magnetic field, while moving charges do?

Comment: Maxwell equations and experiment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No magnetic field from a static charge - Is there a simple physical argument to show why?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51346/)