# Is a magnetic field just a moving charge?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am trying to understand electromagnetism. I would like to pare myself down to the minimum number of necessary concepts.

From my physics education (high school only), I understand that a moving charge **creates** a magnetic field. The implication is that magnetism is a discrete concept that I also need to understand.

However, is this view actually confusing: is it the case that a magnetic field **is** a moving charge?

Either way, a link to a primer accessible to someone with a engineering degree level maths would be wonderful. If it is the case magnetism **is** a moving charge, then an introduction following this approach would be wonderful.

Thank you!

Comment: I found [A Student's Guide to Maxwell's Equations](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Students-Guide-Maxwells-Equations/dp/0521701473) to be a good introductory book.

Comment: Thank you for the link @JohnRennie. I'll grant my maths is a little rusty, but the cover alone is fairly intimidating, unless there's a gentle run up to the notation used there :-)

Comment: The problem is that you can't understand magnetic fields without understand Maxwell's equations - at least in principle if not in all their gory detail. You say *magnetism is a discrete concept* but it isn't. An electromagnetic field can appear as an electric or magnetic field depending on your frame of reference. For the small investment required I would buy the book and have a quick scan through skipping the maths. That will at least give you a starting point.

Comment: Hi Benjohn, what would you say is 'engineering degree level' mathematics. Are you comfortable with calculus?

Comment: @JohnRennie The book sounds good, I'll take a look. Thank you.

Comment: @Danu I'm comfortable with integrals & differentials, which I believe is calculus?

Comment: @Benjohn how about vector calculus?

Comment: @danu At first look, I'm comfortable with [Wikipedia's page on vector calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus) up to the mention of Curl under "Differential operations", which makes some intuitive sense. The "Theorems" section looks scary.

Comment: @Benjohn I would recommend a standard introductory book on electrodynamics (Griffiths' book Introduction to Electrodynamics is the standard in physics curriculums), the first sections will typically offer a concise summary of/intro to vector calculus; you could use one of the standard calculus books which should all cover both single- and multivariable fundamentals to supplement your readings

Comment: I found [this related question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/51346/no-magnetic-field-from-a-static-charge-is-there-a-simple-physical-argument-to) to which the second answer states "magnetism is nothing more than electrostatics combined with relativistic motion", which lead me to Wikipedia's [Relativistic Electromagnetism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_electromagnetism) article, which makes a reasonable amount of sense to me, although I can't see why a stationary charge wouldn't deflect away from the wire instead of  staying still.

Comment: The down-vote seems a little harsh. If this SA is  for Physics practitioners, rather than the curious, I'll take it on the chin :-)

Comment: @Benjohn: I wouldn't pay too much attention to the down vote, there are some miserable beggars lurking on this site (though most of us are quite nice - I think :-). Have a +1 from me to counteract it, anyone who is willing to learn electrodynamics needs encouragement!

Comment: @JohnRennie Thanks! :-) Reassuring to know I'm not doing anything too stupid.